# Goroutine buffered channel deadlock

Tags: go

In the main goroutine, I'm getting a deadlock if I send values to channel exceeded the capacity, but if I'm sending in a different goroutine, there will be no deadlock, Why?

```golang
func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 2)
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        c <- i
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 2)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
            c <- i
        }
        close(c)
    }()
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
}
```

Comment: In the first case, no goroutines can continue. In the second case, the main goroutine can still continue while the new goroutine is blocked waiting to write to the channel.

Comment: "if I send values to channel exceeded the capacity" --- what else do you expect to see there?

Comment: @BurakSerdar A goroutine wont know if there are other channel operations outside, so in the second case, it is possible to continue in the goroutine's point of view, am I right?

Comment: @zerkms I thought I will also get a deadlock in case 2

Comment: Not the goroutine, but the runtime knows if there are other runnable goroutines. In the second case, the main goroutine is never blocked.

Answer (score 0):

```
func main() {
   c := make(chan int, 2)
   for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
       // Blocking operation
       c <- i
   }
}
```

```
By default >>>sends<<< and receives block(!) until both the sender and receiver are ready
```

Checkout - https://gobyexample.com/channels

There are no receivers on your channel, main goroutine(= sender) is blocked